# Can Pebble app launch its companion app programmatically?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

> The Pebble mobile app will attempt to keep your app running as long as
>   your Pebble watchapp is running. However, under certain circumstances,
>   the phone may kill the Pebble app and your app. If this occurs, the
>   Pebble mobile app will be automatically restarted (and your JavaScript
>   code with it).

As Pebble's documentation mentioned [here](https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/pebble-apps/pebblekit-js/#key-concepts), the official Pebble app could be launched automatically while the connected Pebble watch is running a JS extended app.

My question is that can we also launch a companion app programmatically from Pebble watch? And how? I couldn't find any clues on the [developer website](http://developer.getpebble.com).

> Note: PebbleKit Android and PebbleKit iOS cannot be used if the Pebble
>   project contains a PebbleKit JS file. Remove any JavaScript files in
>   the Pebble project to ensure communication with Android and iOS
>   companion apps.

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/mobile-apps/), we can't integrate JS extension together with PebbleKit iOS/Android, that's why it's important to ask this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately this isn't currently possible. Maybe in the future this will be possible by passing around some deep links.

Comment: Actually @cocoabob, you can do this on Android. You can wait for an appmessage from the watch, and programmatically launch an app on the Android side.